# How to handle this use case in Spring Batch - Different Names?

Tags: spring-batch

There is a CSV file with many records where the CSV header names and the DB domain object names are different. How to fetch the CSV data and create a model to persist in the database in Spring Batch? Below throws errors since the header and db or jpa names are different

Example, employee.csv

```
Employee Id, Employee Name, Employee Address, Employee Address 2, Date Of Birth
```

Domain Object Employee.java

```
public string empId;   
public string empName;   
public string empAddress;   
public string empAddress2;   
public string empDOB;
```

Error thrown on the flat file reader

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;

@Component
@JobScope
public class EmployeeFlatFileItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<Employee> implements StepExecutionListener {

private String fileName;
private String filePath;

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    fileName = (String) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters().getString("fileName");  
    filePath = (String) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters().getString("filePath");  
    setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));  
}

public EmployeeFlatFileItemReader() {
    try {
        //init();
        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Employee>() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setNames("Employee Id" + "," + "Employee Name" + "," + "Employee Address" + "," + "Employee Address 2" + "," + "Date Of Birth");
                    }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Employee>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Employee.class); // Throws error
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a single String in the `setNames` method:

```
setNames("Employee Id" + "," + "Employee Name" + "," + "Employee Address" + "," + "Employee Address 2" + "," + "Date Of Birth");
```

This methods takes an array of Strings which correspond to field names in your domain type, not the header of the file (which should be skipped by the way using `setLinesToSkip(1)`.

So you should update that line with something like:

```
setNames("empId" , "empName", "empAddress", "empAddress2", "empDOB");
```

Field names should be in the same order as they appear in the csv file.